# IE title changes to <afterHash> if the page has a url with '#' , and has flash/swf embedded in it

Tags: jquery, flash, browser, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

The issue is, if IE (6.0+) , has flash content embedded in it, and the url of the page has a # somewhere in it, then when the flash content loads ,or if the user interacts with it, then the title of the window, changes to the content that is places after hash.

e.g http://adobeflashwebsite.com/index.html#somediv

Then the title of the page changes to 'somediv' , the moment a user will click on flash content, or many a times even the moment the flash content loads.

### This happens only in IE.

This below is a very specific case I was facing:

The following is the environment I am facing issues with:

1. Shinding engine to show an iGoogle like page
2. Sammy.js
3. Gadgets rendering flash/swf

The issue here is, no matter which plugin I try to embed flash with, I end up having the following problem

1. When the flash loads completely, it appends something like #tab/xx , which actually is a string used by sammy to store the last navigational history within the page
2. When, a user starts interacting with the flash, then the title is completely removed and only #tab/xx remains as the title.
3. When a gadget is refreshed, even then there is issue like #2.

Could someone suggest, what the issue could be?
Most probably is it related to sammy.js, as iGoogle doesn't have that issue.

Comment: @Neeraj BC: please share this with your peers/social networkers.

Comment: I assume that by "browser title" you mean "page url".

Comment: Can you show how you embed the flash?

Comment: No by browser title I mean the title tag existing in the html code which then ends up in the title bar and the tab title physically.Also, irrespective of how I embed (I have tried embedding simply by adding object/embed tags, using swfObj, using AC_OET, using the inbuild swfembed function by shindig), it behaves the same way.

Comment: Ahaa.. now I get it. So app still works and this is just an issue with ugly title.

Comment: Is this on IE? If so, do you see the same problem on other browsers?

Comment: yes this is precisely with IE.The only other browser which the clients use is Firefox, and on that it works just fine.

Comment: Do you actually want the flash gadget(s) to have influence on what address and html title is displayed? This is not flash player native, but added by SWFAddress or a similar library. Could it be that that's in there somewhere, tagged along with the SWFObject distro? Or is Shindig/Sammy mimicking this behavior?

Comment: @epologee: It is IE bug and not tied to any specific library. Same thing happens even without them. See the links in my answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following workaround is the only way (till now) , that I got nearest to solving the issue:

```
var isIE11OrGreater = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/));
if (!isIE11OrGreater) {
    var originalTitle = document.title.split("#")[0];    
    document.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function (evt) {
       if(evt.propertyName === 'title' && document.title !== originalTitle) {
        setTimeout(function () {
           document.title = originalTitle;
        }, 1);
    }
});

}

//Incase the developer wants to change the title manually, instead of directly using     //document.title=newtitle, he will need to use changeTitle(newTitle)
    function changeTitle(newTitle)
    {
        originalTitle = newTitle;
        document.title = newtitle;
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, but beware; when my site embedded two Flash objects at the same time, the original title was duplicated with this code.  Wrapping the changing of the title with a `setTimeout` with 0 duration worked around that.

Comment: This doesnt happen with me.. though I use like 5-6 flash objects on the same page.Not sure what went wrong..

Comment: This gave me a stack overflow in ie

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the right code??from the code there seems to be no place where a recursion would happen.

Comment: The stack overflow does indeed happen in IE. By using setTimeout(..., 1), we can avoid this. I've edited this answer, but I'm commenting in case it never is reviewed.

Comment: @smerchek : I just checked it and it seems that IE8 throws a stackoverflow indeed.Can you please make me understand the issue that was happening and how does using setTimeout help with it

Comment: `document.attachEvent` is [no longer supported for IE 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx). use `addEventListener`

Comment: addEventListener does not support the propertychange event (see the propertychange event documentation on MSDN for details). Seems this workaround will no longer work.

Answer (score 8):

It is IE bug:

- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-240 (includes couple of workarounds)
- http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@jquery.com/msg14509.html
- http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/issues/detail?id=293

If you are using sammy's [`title`](http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/docs/api.html#Sammy.Title) method you could delay the execution a bit to make it behave on IE.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    context.title('Some title');
}, 1000);
```

This won't solve it really, but I have noticed that a little delay helps IE sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really familiar with sammy.js but:

1) the Flash object is somehow 'taking ownership' of the title property.

*OR*

2) sammy.js is clearing the title value on HTML losing focus aka Flash gaining it (less likley and don't know why would someone do that)

If 1) -> define the title property in the Flash object itself (not a Flash user, dunno if it can be done easily)

If 2) -> the javascript is dumping a variable string value connected to the title property?

SUGGESTION:

Enclose your flash object in a new `<div>` element, assigning the `<div>` a *.click()* event handler that changes the title property of a document. Try this:

```
$('title').text('YourTitleHere');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party but I prefer this approach:

```
var originalTitle = document.title;

copyLinkClipboard = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById('copy-link-btn'));

copyLinkClipboard.on( 'ready', function () {
  copyLinkClipboard.on( 'aftercopy', function (event) {
    event.target.blur();
    console.log('Successfully copied link to your clipboard!');
    document.title = originalTitle; // sets the title back on successful copy
  });
});

document.title = originalTitle; // sets title back when it changes on instantiation
```

This specifically changes the title back in the two events that ZeroClipboard changes it, rather than registering a listener on the document.onpropertychange event.

Comment: By interact I did not mean copy specifically. I  meant any interaction, that involved "click", "focus", "hover".

Answer (score 0):

```
//some changes
if (browser.ie < 10) {
    document.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function(evt) {
        if (evt.propertyName === 'title' && document.title) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var b=document.title.indexOf('#');
                if(b!==-1){
                    document.title = document.title.slice(0,b);
                }

            }, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so that future readers can easily understand your solution.