# document title is changing in ie8 on hash change

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to prevent document title change in ie8. because it is changing automatically based on the hash in url (www.#hash)

for example: consider my title is:

```
<head><title>Welcome</title></head>
```

if the hash changes to #691 the title become $691 in IE8:

```
<head><title>#691</title></head>
```

any better solution than

```
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.document.title = "Some title";
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I can not duplicate this behavior

Comment: what have you tried? fixing your HTML might do the trick, because this smells of tag-soup. Try forcing IE8 into (near) standards by using the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)

Comment: There were also some options how to show the page title in the title bar in IE8, but I can't recall any correct term for the name. Please check Internet Options > Advanced, there it was...

Comment: Please take care of the question quality at stackoverflow! What do you mean by "hash", why is the hash changing, provide some examples, what have you done so far, ...

Answer (score 2):

I found a better solution that works on IE9 & IE11.
In modern browsers you can use the generic DOMSubtreeModified event, however In older browsers I used the onpropertychange event, which is only supported in conjunction with the legacy attachEvent IE-only event registration model, which has deprecated since Windows Internet Explorer 9 in favor of the W3C standard "addEventListener" event model.

**Tested on IE9 & IE11**

```js
function handleIETitle() {
  var originalTitle = document.title.split('#')[0];

  window.onload = function () {
    var titleEl = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
    var docEl = document.documentElement;

    if (docEl && docEl.addEventListener) {
      docEl.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function (evt) {
        var t = evt.target;
        if (t === titleEl || (t.parentNode && t.parentNode === titleEl)) {
          if (document.title !== originalTitle) {
            document.title = originalTitle;
          }
        }
      }, false);
    } else {
      document.onpropertychange = function () {
        if (window.event.propertyName === 'title') {
          if (document.title !== originalTitle) {
            document.title = originalTitle;
          }
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is look like an issue with IE(specific to the page that has **swf(flash/flex) embedded**), check the below links

[IE title changes to <afterHash> if the page has a url with '#' , and has flash/swf embedded in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562423/ie-title-changes-to-afterhash-if-the-page-has-a-url-with-and-has-flash-s)

the answer provided by **Heikki**

Answer (score 0):

```
if (browser.ie < 10) {
    document.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function(evt) {
        if (evt.propertyName === 'title' && document.title) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var b=document.title.indexOf('#');
                if(b!==-1){
                    document.title = document.title.slice(0,b);
                }

            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```